# Too much space after first line in table in beamer class

Tags: image, latex, tabular, beamer

I'm working in Latex beamer class and have a table environment in there. For some reason the space between the 1st and the 2nd line is huge and I have no idea where that comes from. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption} \setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{}
\begin{document}
\frame{
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1,5cm}||p{1,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|}\\
& \begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{CDUCSU.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:CDUCSU.png}
\end{figure} &

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{SPD_logo_svg.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:SPD.png}
\end{figure} & 


\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Gruene.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:Gruene.png}
\end{figure}&

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Linke.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:Linke.png}
\end{figure}


&
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Piraten.png}\caption{}\label{fig:Piraten.png}\end{figure} \\\hline
Definition &&&&& \\\hline
political standpoint&&&&& no priorization of data. No  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
\end{document}
```

What I get is this. [image: Output of Latex Table with too much space between logos and next row]

Any idea how I can reduce the space between the logos and the next row?

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: I got rid of some of the space by erasing the     \caption{}. Still, there is quite a lot of space prior to the logos... :( Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Nice question.  I have no special insights, so this comment is speculative. Have you checked the sizes of the icons that you are putting in the problematic row?  Perhaps one or more of the images is larger than it appears (e.g. because it is surrounded by whitespace) and is demanding a lot of space for the row.  The ImageMagick [identify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) can be helpful for this check.

Comment: can I somehow migrate this question to the Tex-forum myself? Or should I just delete it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use a `figure` environment in order to insert a figure into your document. The `figure` environment is merely a floating box that has a caption set to `Figure` and that's that. You can even place a `tabular` inside a `figure` environment, or just text, or just a caption...

In that sense, since you're not using the `\caption`, you should just use

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{1.5cm}|| *{5}{X|} }
    & \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      & \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
      & \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-c}
      & \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      & \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
    \hline
    Definition & & & & & \\
    \hline
    Political standpoint & & & & & no priorization of data. No
  \end{tabularx}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that I've used [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) in order to have a `tabular` that has a fixed width (`\textwidth`) without having to specify the column widths for columns 2-6. The `X`-column figures out exactly how wide they should be in order to fit the entire `tabularx` into `\textwidth`. You don't have to do this, but it makes for a consistently nice view.

Also, length specifications require a period for decimals. That is, `1.5cm`, not `1,5cm`.

---

Of course, the same discussion above holds for the `table` environment. There's no need to use a `table` environment if you want to place a `tabular` (my code shows this).